# Database implementation in order to save user activity information

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, android-activity

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and MySQL.

In my project I would like to create an activity-stream "module" in order to save each user action information in a dedicated user table. That is, to create a database table for each user.

Is it a good approach to create a database table for each (new registered) user in my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not a good approach. Why would you create a separate tables with all the same fields? Just add `user_id` to your table and store all info for every user in there.

Comment: I am a little "scared" because, considering large amounts of data, database queries may be slow using your solution.

Comment: See my similar comment below. By making sure that the `user_id` is defined first in a composite index (PRIMARY, UNIQUE or straight INDEX) you should find that the queries are still fine performance-wise.

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar, and it's not necessary to create a whole table for each user. For example, I have a table called "user_actions", and in it there is a column, "user_id".

The relationships are:

User `has_many :user_actions`

UserAction `belongs_to :user`

And you're done. Let the foreign-key relationship that comes naturally take care tying the specific action to a specific user.

Once you do that, you only need to decide:

1. Which actions cause an entry to be added?
2. How long should you retain the data (1 week, 6 months)?

For example, on my site, I keep a log of the last 5 things a user viewed, and present that list to them on a section of the page called "Recently viewed items" for convenience.

I also have a separate table called "admin_actions" that I use for security logging that keeps track of everything done under an admin account, and what admin account made what sort of change.

Answer (score -2):

I guess the answer is that it depends on how many users there are. If it's not a small, defined number then I'd suggest that it's not a good idea to create one table per user.

I'd suggest a single table with one column being a unique identifier for the user. Make sure that whenever you're querying the table that you're using an index that has this column as the first column in the key. E.g. `PRIMARY KEY(user_id, activity_time)`

This should allow for fast and efficient reading of the rows.

Comment: I think the "depends on how many users there are" is just flat incorrect. There's no reason to create a table for every user. This is inefficient, and would also require changing your database schema on the fly, while the program is running, and new users are created.

Comment: If it was a small *defined* number then there'd be no need to create tables on the fly. And a down-vote?! What a joker.

Comment: Can you present a counter example of when this is actually done, and is necessary? The __defined__ part has nothing to do with it - if your application has exactly 2, or 5, or 15 users (for example), and that's never going to change, you're suggesting a table for each of them? That's just needless duplication. I'll be happy to change my vote if you can provide a real-world example, and/or reasons why (security, structure, etc.) this would be justified.

Comment: I think you just down-voted my first paragraph and not the valid solution.

Comment: Hey James, not trying to start anything here. You are correct - I only take issue with your first paragraph. The whole point of the voting system is to raise the best questions to the top. If you want to change your answer, which you have full access to do, I'll be happy to remove my vote. As it stands, your first paragraph, in my opionion, seriously weakens what is otherwise a great answer.